# PIL changes file name while saving

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When I use the save method in PIL to save a file, it saves it by the right file name I provide, but on clicking on the file name the path shows to be different. (Sorry, my explanation sucks).

For example, if u go to http://shopperspoll.webfactional.com/media/images/emailTemplate/mergedImages/
there is an image named "7962716_41tlK2uT%2BSL.*SL75*.png". On clicking on the image though, the name of the file that shows up on the browser changes to "7962716_41tlK2uT%252BSL.*SL75*.png" with the additional "52" in the file name. I am using `image.save(pathName)` to save the image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `7962716_41tlK2uT%2BSL.SL75.png` is a valid filename, it is saved on your filesystem. The browser urlencodes the filename, so `7962716_41tlK2uT%2BSL.SL75.png` becomes `7962716_41tlK2uT%252BSL.SL75.png`; the percent sign in your filename becomes `%25`.

So PIL does not change your filename, your browser escapes your actual filename. That's all!

Given a query with the parameter `q`, you get:

```
>>>urllib.urlencode({'q':'7962716_41tlK2uT%2BSL.SL75.png'}) == "q=7962716_41tlK2uT%252BSL.SL75.png"
True
```